# Parsing JSON data from JSP

Tags: jquery, json, jsp

i have a jsp on a server that returns me a JSON like this: {"link":"LINK_TEST","title":"TITLE_TEST"}

I am trying to get this data from a client html page but i can do it.

this is the jsp code:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>
<%@page import="org.json.simple.JSONObject"%>
<%
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    json.put("title", "TITLE_TEST");
    json.put("link", "LINK_TEST");
    out.print(json);
    out.flush();
%>
```

The jsp looks like this: {"link":"LINK_TEST","title":"TITLE_TEST"}

And this is the client side code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>        
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
            $.ajax({
                url : 'http://my_ip:my_port/json.jsp',
                data : { search: 'test' },
                dataType: 'json',
                success : function(json) {

                var ob = jQuery.parseJSON(json);
                alert(ob.link+" "+ob.title);

                document.getElementById("uno").innerHTML = ob.link;
                document.getElementById("dos").innerHTML = ob.title;
                }

            });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <h1 id="uno"></h1>
    <h1 id="dos"></h1>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: jQuery will already be deserialising the JSON for you as you set `dataType: ;json'`, so you can remove the `var ob = jQuery.parseJSON(json);` line. Please check the console for any other errors. Also note that jQuery 1.5.1 is *very* outdated. You should be using 1.12 at the oldest.

Comment: Thanks @Rory McCrossan i will make the changes

Comment: And what is the result ? What is the value of json ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   Put it inside document.ready it will work and comment out datatype . i..e,
   <pre>
   &lt;script&gt;
    $(document ).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url : 'http://localhost:8080/json.jsp',
        data : { search: 'test' },
        success : function(json) {
            var ob = jQuery.parseJSON(json);
            alert(ob.link+" "+ob.title);
            document.getElementById("uno").innerHTML = ob.link;
            document.getElementById("dos").innerHTML = ob.title;
        }
     });
   });
   &lt;/script&gt;
   </pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
//start ajax request
    $.ajax({
        url: "data.json",
        //force to handle it as text
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(data) {

            //data downloaded so we call parseJSON function 
            //and pass downloaded data
            var json = $.parseJSON(data);
            //now json variable contains data in json format
            //let's display a few items
            for (var i=0;i<json.length;++i)
            {
                $('#results').append('<div class="name">'+json[i].name+'</>');
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I dont know why but it doesn't work my friend @Albin